# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined at Component.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `Counter` component stays with `0`. Has *this* bound nowhere so that caught the error?

```
class Counter extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)

        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }

        setInterval(this.setState, 1000, {
            count: this.state.count + 1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <p>{this.state.count}</p>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setInterval` (and `setState`) syntax should be like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.setState(state => ({
    count: state.count + 1
  }));
}, 1000)
```

- [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) takes a function and a delay (in your case).
- [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) can take an object or a function, in your case its
  better to use the function version as the next state depends on the
  current state. As `setState` is asynchronous it may be out of sync if
  you will use the object version.

Running example:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        count: state.count + 1
      }));
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return <p > {
      this.state.count
    } < /p>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: The error is gone, but the counter stays unchanged with `0` .

Comment: I've added a running example, make sure you wrote it like i did.